# Does suggesting potential reviewers for one's submitted paper increase the likelihood of the paper being accepted?

Tags: publications, peer-review, reference-request

Some journals propose authors to suggest potential reviewers for their submitted papers.

Is there any research/study/survey that tried to quantify to what extent  suggesting potential reviewers for one's submitted paper impacts the likelihood of the paper being accepted?

Comment: Being in a position to suggest reviewers probably means you are integrated in to your research community and accepted within it. One's prior success is likely the best predictor of future success.

Comment: Suggested reviewers are often a path to collusion as well.  I don't think naming them helps your chances.

Comment: @JonCuster However, the ancedotal evidence here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10474/19607 suggests that suggesting reviewers _lowers_ the likelihood of a paper being accepted (interpreted in an appropriate statistical sense).

Comment: I highly doubt there has been a study on this, and you will not get more than ancedotal evidence such as in the post I linked to above.

Comment: One journal I sent one of my articles to had the **requirement** of naming 4 potential reviewers. If you did not name any or not enough, your submission was not accepted. I don't know if this is the case with other journals as well, but in this instance, it did not improve your chances at all.